# JOptionPane.showInputDialog with String in input field

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, joptionpane

I'm using `JOptionPane.showInputDialog("correct the following string");` and want a certain string to be already entered in the input field of the dialog when the dialog opens. Is that possible with `JOptionPane`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this in place of JOptionPane.showInputDialog("correct the following string");

```
String mystr = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,
                    "correct the following string", "correct the following string");
```